# Install Windows Service On Windows Vista

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Yes Vista sucks... I'm writing a Windows Service using .Net but getting security errors when trying to install with InstallUtil.exe.

How can I install the Windows Service successfully in Windows Vista?

Comment: What error do you get? Is it during installation or during start up of your service? Is UAC enabled? Are you installing from an administrative command prompt?

Comment: Oh I see the mistake I made... I didn't run the command prompt as administrative :-( cool its working fine now thanks.

Comment: @Lennie: I guess it didn't suck too bad, after all. Also, I presume you've been providing Microsoft with feedback on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `installutil.exe` from an elevated cmd (search command prompt in start menu, right click, run as administrator).

Answer (score 0):

- Press the Start button
- Type cmd in the search box
- When Command Shell comes up right click, select Run as Administrator

Now you have command shell with full admin permissions. InstallUtil at will.

Comment: In step 3 you can also press Ctrl+Shift+Return to start cmd.exe as Administrator.